# custom chapterstyle

Tags: memoir

I'm trying to make a custom chapterstyle with `memoir`, but the result is not that pleasing.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\makechapterstyle{jonas}{%
  \chapterstyle{demo2}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
  \hrule \vskip .5\onelineskip%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1cm);
        \draw[color=white] (.5cm,.5cm) node {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      \hfill%
    }
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\hrule \vskip .6\onelineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
      \raggedleft \adjustbox{%
          varwidth=\textwidth-1.5cm,
        }{\chaptitlefont ##1}%
    }
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip.5\onelineskip \hrule\vskip \afterchapskip}
}

\chapterstyle{jonas}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{hello}
\chapter{Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction}
\chapter{Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction }
\end{document}
```

In the picture below I've highlighted some of the current inconsistencies.

[image]

My goal is to have:

- Both chapter number and chapter title vertically centered.
- A constant space between chapter number and chapter title
- A constant space between the tallest of the two elements and the two horizontal bars.

Comment: Maybe you can centered the chapter number and chapter font if you put them inside a tabular environment ... when run your code, the chapter name appears at right because \raggedleft. This is for numbered or no numbered chapter, due that not appears constant space between chapter number and chapter title ...